# Where there is an existing custom close reason show that in the review summary rather than "Other (add a comment to explain why)"

Tags: feature-request, review, vote-to-close

### Background

While [reviewing](https://stackoverflow.com/review/close/3262810) for close votes the summary is invaluable in showing quickly how others have voted. However when a custom reason was previously selected it shows as "Other (add a comment to explain why)" (which actually led me to think someone has left that as their reason).

[image]

While within "Close" you can find the real reason:

[image]

### Proposal

- Best case scenario add the custom reason in "off-topic: .....", so in this case "off-topic: This question appears to be off topic because it is about (1) legal and (2) asking whether a third party tool can be relied upon"
- Failing that simply have "off-topic: Other" as the "(add a comment explaining what is wrong)" is clearly not useful here and is mildly confusing